# How to get acceptable adjusted r squared value in LSTM algorithm for sales prediction?

Tags: regression, lstm, data-science

I'm using past 12 months as lag to fit the regression,for lag1 I'm getting the value 10%, for lag 1-lag 5 I'm getting 45% but when I'm trying to include all lag 1-lag 12, I'm getting "nan". And it seems adjusted r squared value is found out for lag 1-lag 9 only but it's only 50% which is not acceptable. I understand the dataset might be over-whelming. I'm new to this kind of algorithm